# react native focus next input with InputAccessoryView

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-native

I am using InputAccessoryView to create a button above the nonnumeric/default keyboard. The issue I am facing is when I press the input accessory button to move focus to the next input, I am getting an error of you can't access ".current of ref".

I would like to move to the next input by using the input accessory button and not the onSubmitEditing. code is as follows:

```js
const Signup = () => {
  const inputAccessoryViewID = 'uniqueIDdddd';
  const inputRefs = [React.createRef(), React.createRef(), React.createRef()];

  const goToNextInput = index => {
    inputRefs[index + 1].current.focus();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ScrollView
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
        keyboardDismissMode="interactive"
      >
        {inputRefs.map((k, idx) => (
          <>
            <TextInput
              onChangeText={setText}
              value={text}
              inputAccessoryViewID={inputAccessoryViewID}
              style={{ height: 40, width: 200, margin: 12, borderWidth: 1 }}
              ref={inputRefs[idx]}
            />
            <InputAccessoryView nativeID={inputAccessoryViewID}>
              /** Press this button to move to the next input */
              <Button onPress={() => goToNextInput(idx)} title="Next" />
            </InputAccessoryView>
          </>
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
    </>
  );
};
```